# Will the following result in two HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var img = new Image();
$(img).attr('src', "<?php echo $image_url; ?>");

$(window).load(function(e){
    resetImageSize(img);
    td.css('background-image', 'url("<?php echo $image_url; ?>")');
});

$(window).resize(function(e){
    resetImageSize(img);
});

function resetImageSize(img){
    var wr = $("#wrapper");
    var td = $("#wrapper td");

    if(img.width > wr.width() || img.height > wr.height()){
        td.css('background-size', 'contain');
    } else {
        td.css('background-size', img.width);
    }
}
```

How can I know?

Comment: Try it and see? Use the network tab in Chrome's inspector to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know how many http request are made by your application, you could use the developper tools of your web brower.

With google chrome press F12, and go to network panel

Your browser will use his cache for the second request, and he will tell you in the result field of the network panel

Answer (score 0):

One way to know how many http request have entered is to look at the server log.

Answer (score 0):

The server should respond that the cache has been utilized for the second request as long as the client does not have it disabled on the browser.  You can test this by analyzing your page in Firebug, using the Net panel.  You should see the image download for the first request and a 304 Resource Not Modified for the second request.

Comment: surely `304` is a _server side_ response, indicating that the cached version is still appropriate?  It's still another HTTP request.  If the browser decided to pre-emptively cache it (based on previous cache control headers) then you wouldn't see a second request.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for the further information, I didn't make this apparent in my response.